# How to display the first line that contains a certain string in a text file unix?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Was hoping someone can help out with this. I am trying to figure out how to display the first line that contains a certain string i.e. "computer" (first occurrence of "computer" in a txt file).  I would prefer to do this using grep.

I know `grep "computer" somefile.txt`

would display all of the lines including "computer".
I am eager to learn and if anyone has alternative ways I would like to hear!

Thx everyone

Comment: Do you mean "contains" or "not containing"?  Your question seem to talk about both...

Comment: `-n` will print the line number in the file. Just a supplement to all the answers.

Comment: @squiguy And -A 3 will print the 3 lines after the match, so what. We are not rewriting the man page for grep :-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish I was just saying if the poster would like to see the line number is all.

Comment: @squiguy But they did not ask for that, nor the next 3 lines after the match or any other of the myriad of options that grep supports. Do not be a politician and answer the question you wanted rather than the question asked ;-)

Comment: :) thanks guys for the feedback I just wanted the first occurrence of it in the file :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the match count option of grep

```
grep -m 1 "computer" somefile.txt
```

Note that grep is non standard across un*x's so while http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/ supports this, if your distro or unix does not this will not work.

Comment: Cool - and as the other guys showed - there is more than one way to do this

Comment: Please note that this option may not exist in your version of `grep`, as it is nonstandard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/grep.html

Comment: @AdrianCornish sorry, StackOverflow did something funny with the angle brackets I used.  Fixed

Comment: @singpolyma Agree it is not Open Group compliant, but the OP did mention linux, where this does work (most of the time :-) if the distro uses the GNU version http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/ - will add this to my answer

Comment: @AdrianCornish I have same kind of requirement, but I want second line as the output. Can we achieve this by using 'grep'?

Answer (score 11):

Pipes are your friend:

```
grep "computer" somefile.txt | head -n1
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this homework?

```
grep -v "computer" somefile.txt | head -n 1
```

Comes to mind the quickest.

Comment: I am just trying out exercises. By the way that only displays the first line of the file ... Not the first occurrence of "computer"

Comment: That's because of the "-v". -v in grep means: "Doesn't match"